# Check if all elements in an array are equal

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

In the first part I am creating pairs out of array elements and the array is twice as short. The array is always even.

Here is the first part:

```
using System;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    int[] Arr = new int[]{1, 2, 0, 3, 4, -1};
    int[] newArr = new int[(Arr.Length / 2)];

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i+=2)
    {
        if (i + 1 < Arr.Length)
        {
            newArr[sum] = Arr[i] + Arr[i + 1];
        }
        else
        {
            newArr[sum] = Arr[i];
        }
        sum++;
    }
```

in the second part I would like to check if the array elements are equal. What I want to do is to increment int counter each time the index in the for loop is equal to the next index in the array.

What I have as second part:

```
int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < newArr.Length -1; i++)
    {
        if (newArr[i] == newArr[i + 1])
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
    }
```

What is wrong in this code. I cannot seem to understand how to write code that will work with int Arr[5] and int Arr[5000]

Comment: `i < newArr.Length - 1`

Comment: now I understand the exception that I get in Visual Studio

Comment: it will crash at `newArr[i + 1]` when `i` is equal to `newArr.Length - 1`, you should iterate from `0` to `< newArr.Length-1`

Comment: If you can use linq, shortest way to check if all array elements are equal is to write newArr.All(a => a == newArr[0]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to change is the termination condition in the `for` loop to

```
i < newArr.Length - 1
```

so that you can compare `array[i]` with `array[i + 1]`. This change makes sure you do not get past the upper bound of the array.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for ( i=1;i<arr.Length;i++)
{
    if(arr[0]==arr[i])
    continue;

    else
    break;
}
if (i==arr.Length)
Console.WriteLine("All element in array are equal");
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need to write so imperative code, other than to achieve your final goal – you don't have to. Almost always you can do it in a much more readable way.

I suggest using LINQ. For collections implementing `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
newArr.Distinct().Take(2).Count() == 1
```

*LINQ is a built-in feature*, just make sure you are `using System.Linq;` at the top of your `.cs` file.

**What goes on here?**

- `Distinct` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, its enumeration will give all distinct elements from your array, but no enumeration, and hence computation, happened yet.
- `Take` returns new `IEnumerable<T>`, its enumeration will enumerate previous `IEnumerable<T>` internally, but it will give only first two distinct elements. Again, no enumeration happened yet.
- At last, `Count` enumerates the last `IEnumerable<T>` and returns its elements count (in our case `0`, `1` or `2`).
- As we used `Take(2)`, the enumeration initiated by `Count` method will be stopped right when the second distinct element is found. If we don't use `Take(2)`, our code will enumerate the whole array even if it is not needed.

**Why is this approach better?**

- *Much shorter* and *more readable*;
- *Lazy evaluation* – if an element is found out to be distinct from the other ones, the enumeration will be stopped immediately;
- *Flexible* – you can pass a custom equality comparer to `Distinct` method. You can also call `Select` method before calling `Distinct` to choose what specific member your elements will be compared by;
- *Universal* – Works with any collection which impletents `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

**Other ways**

The same result can be achieved in slightly other ways, for example:

```
!newArr.Distinct().Take(2).Skip(1).Any()
```

Experiment with LINQ and choose the way you and your team consider the most readable.

For collections implementing `IList<T>` you can also write (as @Alexander suggested):

```
newArr.All(x => x == newArr[0])
```

This variant is shorter but not as flexible and universal.

---

***OFF TOPIC.* Encapsulating common code**

You should encapsulate code that does one simple thing into a separate method, it further improves your code readability and allows reusing your method in several places. I'd write an extension method for this one.

```
public static class CollectionExtensions {
    public static bool AllElementsEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) {
        return items.Distinct().Take(2).Count() == 1;
    }
}
```

Later in your code you need just to call this method:

```
newArr.AllElementsEqual()
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this..

```
for (int i = 0; i < newArr.Length-1; i++)
{
 for(int j=0 ;j< newArr.Length-1; i++)
      {
      if (newArr[i] == newArr[j])
       {
            /////
        }
       }

    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. you never compare last element with others; 2. what's the point in conversion of O(n) operation to O(n^2)?